# Android unable to receive notification when app is killed using FCM

Tags: java, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

> Android able to receive notification when app is in foreground and background but when I kill it causing  unable to receive notification.

> I'm not sure what part was wrong.

> code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

> MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

> I don't create MyFirebaseIdService.java for refresh token. I use  onNewToken(String mToken) in this class instead.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(String mToken) {
    super.onNewToken(mToken);
    Log.e("NEW_TOKEN",mToken);
}
```

> Here is my onMessageReceived code.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());


    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        sendNotification(notification, data);
    }

}
```

> sendNotification code, I attempt make it to receive both data payload and notification payload but it still not work.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification, Map<String, String> data) {

    String title;
    String body;

    if (data != null) {
        title = data.get("title");
        body = data.get("body");
    } else {
        title = notification.getTitle();
        body = notification.getBody();
    }

    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setColor(Color.BLUE)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    try {
        String picture_url = data.get("picture_url");
        if (picture_url != null && !"".equals(picture_url)) {
            URL url = new URL(picture_url);
            Bitmap bigPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(
                    new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bigPicture).setSummaryText(notification.getBody())
            );
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    notificationBuilder.setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 300);

    NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
```

> create channel code

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                "channel_id", "channel_name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );
        channel.setDescription("channel description");
        channel.setShowBadge(true);
        channel.canShowBadge();
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500});
        managerCompat.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    managerCompat.notify(101,notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Comment: You wanna us to help you only putting your code. Tell your achieve, your current problem ecc... If you have noticed if a part of your code is the right one

Comment: thank you, I'm already editing.

Comment: have you tried your code on different devices? have you tested this on emulator?

Comment: yes, it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot receive notification when killed app for one cause:

Some manufacturers, like HUAWEI, OPPO ecc... make unavailable to push notifications while app is not running, this in order to save your battery life. Of course, important app (WhatsApp, Instagram ecc...) make exception by default. In other hand, there's a way to fix it, every app can get this permission manually via settings->battery (it changes phone by phone).

Now you have to find this permission which affords app to push notifications without running. A tip: when I've tick this one, it doesn't work; I had to unistall app via settings->app, then re-install it again

Comment: I don't think this is related. Your app doesn't need to be running to receive cloud messages.

Comment: He doesn't get notification when app is killed, I had this problem and fixed in this way. Maybe I didn't understand his achieve